# Passing data to a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery

I have 5 images with relevant data.If i visited all the images i need to show modal box with some message"You have visited all the images". otherwise "please visit all the images".But am getting empty modal box.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        $('.modal-body').html('')
        if($('.img').hasClass('visited')){
         $('modal-body').append('<p>you have successfully visited all the images</p>');
        }else{
         $('modal-body').append('<p>please visit all the images</p>');
        }

    });
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `$('modal-body')` should be `$('.modal-body')`

Comment: assuming that your #submit button is working, then the logical guess .modal-body, you miss (.) DOT in your code

Comment: what do you mean by " visited all the images"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your condition to something similar to this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        $('.modal-body').html('')
        if($('.img.visited').length  >= 5){
         $('modal-body').append('<p>you have successfully visited all the images</p>');
        }else{
         $('modal-body').append('<p>please visit all the images</p>');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you miss . (DOT) notation in your code. It should be

```
$('.modal-body').append('<p>you have successfully visited all the images</p>');
```

and

```
$('.modal-body').append('<p>please visit all the images</p>');
```

Comment: @moksha then solution below me by @madalin should work, you miss `$('.img.visited').length` to count visited images, if it doesn't work, you should check your code that adding `.visited` class to your image elements

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
        $('.modal-body').html('')
        if($('.img.visited').length  >= 5){
         $('.modal-body').append('<p>you have successfully visited all the images</p>');
        }else{
         $('.modal-body').append('<p>please visit all the images</p>');
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
```